# Calling REST API using Javascript using username and password?

Tags: javascript, php, html, rest

I am trying to call **AwaazDe REST API** using Javascript using some username and password. But it is not working. Here is my code

```
 function authenticateUser(user, password)
    {
        var token = user + ":" + password;

        // Should i be encoding this value????? does it matter???
        // Base64 Encoding -> btoa
        var hash = btoa(token); 

        return "Basic " + hash;
    }

    /*function UserAction() {*/
   /* alert("Searching!");*/
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "https://awaaz.de:443/console/streams-api/groups/", false);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    /*xhttp.setRequestHeader("username", "saurabh134741@nitp.ac.in");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("password", "12345");*/
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", authenticateUser("username","password"));  
    xhttp.send();
    var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
    alert("No response");
/*}*/
```

Please help me with this issue. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: not working is pretty vague word be specific in terms of any error you getting that might help

Comment: Not working means not getting the content using GET method using REST API.

Comment: @SaurabhSinha Turn on your browser debugger(NET) console and check for further info. It will save your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not working because https://awaaz.de:443/ not allowed to cross-domain request 
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://awaaz.de/console/streams-api/groups/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing

Comment: Any solution? or it is not possible to call AwaazDe API using Javascript?

Comment: if your application set on same server than it's work perfectly.if you need to test and code at development time than use google chrome browser "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *" extension